# Need to implement a recursive mergesort code in C using array pointer, its length and a workspace array for the merge function

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, merge, mergesort

I need to implement mergesort for arrays up to 100000 integers but the specifications are a bit troublesome: I need to use a pointer to an integer array, its length and an extra workspace array for merging,

The `mergesort` function should look something like this:

```
void merge_sort(int *a, int *w, int n)
```

where `a` is to be sorted and `w` is the workspace used for merging, cant use an array and two indexes between what I wanna sort

pseudocode:

```
merge_sort(int *a, int *w, int n) {
   /* take care of stopping condition first */
   if the array to be sorted has fewer than two elements then
       return

   merge_sort( first half of array a);
   merge_sort( second half of array a);

   merge the two halves of array a into array w
   copy array w back into array a
}


merge(int *array, int *workspace, int len) {
    initialise indices to point to the beginning of
    the left and right halves of array

    while there are elements in both halves of array {
        compare the elements at the current left and right indices
        put the smallest into workspace and increment both the index
        it was taken from, and the index in workspace
    }

    add any remaining elements from left half of array to workspace
    add any remaining elements from right half of array to workspace
}
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_MAX 100000

void merge_sort(int *a, int *w, int n) {

    if (n == 1)
        return;
    else {
        int *temp;
        merge_sort(a, w, n / 2);
        merge_sort(a + (n / 2), w, (n - (n / 2)));

        /** Cannot figure what to pass to merge since it has to be the two halves          
            and how to copy contents of a to w **/

    } 
}

void merge(int *a, int *w, int n) {
    /** Cannot figure this out **/
}

int main(void) {
    int my_array[ARRAY_MAX];
    int work_space[ARRAY_MAX];
    int count = 0;
    int i;

    while (count < ARRAY_MAX && 1 == scanf("%d", &my_array[count])) {
         count += 1;
    }

    start = clock();
    merge_sort(my_array, workspace, count);
    end = clock();

    merge_sort(my_array, work_space, count);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", my_array[i]);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%d %f \n", count, (end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Show us what you tried and didn't work.

Comment: @Sandy please check the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The merging phase in function `merge_sort` iterates on both *halves* in parallel, taking the smallest element from either side at a time:

```
void merge_sort(int *a, int *w, int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    } else {
        int i, j, k;
        int n1 = n / 2;
        int *b = a + n1;
        int n2 = n - n1;

        /* sort the left half */
        merge_sort(a, w, n1);
        /* sort the right half */
        merge_sort(b, w, n2);

        /* merge the halves into w */
        for (i = j = k = 0; i < n1 && j < n2;) {
            if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
                /* get smallest value from a */
                w[k++] = a[i++];
            } else {
                /* get smallest value from b */
                w[k++] = b[j++];
            }
        }
        /* copy remaining elements from a */
        while (i < n1) {
            w[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        /* copy remaining elements from b */
        while (j < n2) {
            w[k++] = b[j++];
        }
        /* copy sorted elements back to a */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = w[i];
        }
    } 
}
```

The rest of the code has a few issues too:

- 2 arrays of 100000 ints might exceed the space available for automatic variables.
- you sort the array twice
- `start` and `end` are not defined

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_MAX 100000

int main(void) {
    int my_array[ARRAY_MAX];
    int work_space[ARRAY_MAX];
    int i, count;
    clock_t start, end;

    count = 0;
    while (count < ARRAY_MAX && scanf("%d", &my_array[count]) == 1) {
        count += 1;
    }

    start = clock();
    merge_sort(my_array, workspace, count);
    end = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", my_array[i]);
    }

    fprintf(stderr,"%d %f\n", count, (end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I properly understand the concepts of pointers now, I was confused on what to do with them because I didnt know how they worked but its working now and its very efficient! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in C, when you send an array as an argument to a function, what is really sent is a pointer to the first element. Then you can use that pointer inside the function in a way very similar to an array. So if you are confused about the ”pointers” in the description of (I assume) your homework, perhaps that is the reason?